# How to make message to DirectExchange auto-dropped if there is no queue listening that key

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq

I have such a scenario that I am not sure if Bunny can support:
I have a Producer that periodically produce messages. And there are 3 consumers. Because I want to mimic the RPC,so instead of using Fanout Exchange, every round my producer send three messages to DirectExchange with corresponding routing key. And consumer will get the message and reply to the temporary reply queue.
So the question is, my Consumer is not always online(I was implementing RAFT consensus algorithm). But when it comes online previous "stale" messages sent by Producer just come through and my just-online consumer started to process so many RPC message that's already not valid, which break my application logic.
Is there any way I can send a message to DirectExchange, and if there is not a queue listening to the routing key, the message just get dropped? I am considering make a Timestamp before sending and check timestamp when received, but this is clearly not a good solution since the "stale threshold" is hard to settle.
Thank you so much guys! Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [message TTL](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html). Maybe setting TTL to 0 is what you want.

> Setting the TTL to 0 causes messages to be expired upon reaching a
>   queue unless they can be delivered to a consumer immediately.

Pay attention that this can be set per queue and per message. Also I'll just quote caveats from the link:

> While consumers never see expired messages, only when expired messages
>   reach the head of a queue will they actually be discarded (or
>   dead-lettered). When setting a per-queue TTL this is not a problem,
>   since expired messages are always at the head of the queue. When
>   setting per-message TTL however, expired messages can queue up behind
>   non-expired ones until the latter are consumed or expired. Hence
>   resources used by such expired messages will not be freed, and they
>   will be counted in queue statistics (e.g. the number of messages in
>   the queue).